# C# Unity3D - How can I use a INT from other classes?

Tags: c#, unity

I have 3 Objects Capsule 1, Capsule 2 and Capsule 3. Every Capsule has a script on it for health/damage. It also contains an int for hits and points. Hits should be increased by one for every bullet that hits the target. Points if it gets destroyed (After 3 hits). 
These ints for points and hits should be displayed as a TextMesh. But how can I add 3 different ints to an Textmesh?
Tried this code, but middle and right doesn't exist in context.

```
meshPoints.text = "Points: " + (points_right + points_middle + points_left) + "\nHits: " + hits_right;
```

How is that possible?

Using one script "health" on all of the objects doesn't work as well because after an object gets destroyed the ints become resetted...

Answer (score 0):

You should collect the 3 capsule objects like

```
GameObject[] capsules = GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("capsule");
```

(perhaps you should add a tag to your gameobjects) and then your line will be

```
meshPoints.text = "Points: " + (capsules[0].GetComponent<ScriptAttached>().points_right + capsules[1].GetComponent<ScriptAttached>().points_middle + capsules[2].GetComponent<ScriptAttached>().points_left) + "\nHits: " + hits_right;
```

Comment: thanks, I created a class for every capsule with contains the hit and points int. Then I was able to access the ints from the other capsules as well. That was what I was looking for. I maybe try your solution later, too.